# Working with span objects. [spaCy, python]

Tags: python, spacy

I'm not sure if this is a really dumb question, but here goes.

```
text_corpus = '''Insurance bosses plead guilty\n\nAnother three US insurance executives have pleaded guilty to fraud charges stemming from an ongoing investigation into industry malpractice.\n\nTwo executives from American International Group (AIG) and one from Marsh & McLennan were the latest. The investigation by New York attorney general Eliot Spitzer has now obtained nine guilty pleas. The highest ranking executive pleading guilty on Tuesday was former Marsh senior vice president Joshua Bewlay.\n\nHe admitted one felony count of scheming to defraud and faces up to four years in prison. A Marsh spokeswoman said Mr Bewlay was no longer with the company. Mr Spitzer\'s investigation of the US insurance industry looked at whether companies rigged bids and fixed prices. Last month Marsh agreed to pay $850m (£415m) to settle a lawsuit filed by Mr Spitzer, but under the settlement it "neither admits nor denies the allegations".\n'''

def get_entities(document_text, model):
    analyzed_doc = model(document_text)
    entities = [entity for entity in analyzed_doc.ents if entity.label_ in ["PER", "ORG", "LOC", "GPE"]]
    return entities
model = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
entities_1 = get_entities(text_corpus, model)
entities_2 = get_entities(text_corpus, model)
```

but when it run  the following,

```
entities_1[0] in entities_2
```

The output is `False`.

Why is that? The objects in both the entity lists are the same. Yet an item from one list is not in the other one. That's extremely odd. Can someone please explain why that is so to me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way `ents`'s are represented in spaCy. They are classes with specific implementations so even `entities_2[0] == entities_1[0]` will evaluate to `False`. By the looks of it, the [Span](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/span.pyx) class does not have an implementation of `__eq__` which, at first glance at least, is the simple reason why.

If you print out the value of entities_2[0] it will give you US but this is simply because the span class has a `__repr__` method implemented in the same file. If you want to do a boolean comparison, one way would be to use the `text` property of `Span` and do something like:

```
entities_1[0].text in [e.text for e in entities_2]
```

edit:

As @abb pointed out, `Span` implements `__richcmp__`, however this is applicable to the same instance of `Span` since it checks the position of the token itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense to me now.

Comment: @AvijeetKartikay , if this solution worked for you, then please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: (`Span` implements `__eq__` in its cython `__richcmp__` method, but spans from different documents are never equal regardless of the contents. If they're from the same document, they need to have the same start/end/label.)

Comment: Thanks @aab, somehow I completely missed `__richcmp__` while I was looking at it. Nice catch!

Comment: I looked at the source code of the `__richcmp__` method and it seems more than the three above mentioned attributes need to align. It needs to be doc, start_char, end_char, label and kb_id.
Source: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/6f65e2b5449d854d5342d379e713ef3645c52a74/spacy/tokens/span.pyx#L123